# Add time delay to TimeseriesGenerator?

Tags: python, keras

I'm using keras `TimeseriesGenerator` function to create a samples and targets but want to add a time delay to the output (i.e. shift the target by some time steps). I see in the documentation there is no native support for adding a delay. How can I add it manually? Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

X = np.arange(100000).reshape(10000, 10)
y = np.arange(50000).reshape(10000, 5)

timesteps = 50
step = 1
delay = 20
batch_size = 20

gener = TimeseriesGenerator(X, y, timesteps, sampling_rate=1,
                            stride=step, start_index=0, end_index=None, shuffle=False, reverse=False, batch_size=batch_size)
```

The output of the first batch for y is `[[250. 251. 252. 253. 254.], [...]` but I want the output to be shifted by a delay of 20 time steps. So the y for first batch should actually start with
`[[350. 351. 352. 353. 354. 355], [...]`

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the TimeseriesGenerator class to implement this functionality e.g., by using numpy.roll

```
class TSGen(keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator):

def __init__(self, delay, **kwargs):
    self.targets = kwargs['targets']
    self.delay = delay
    kwargs['targets'] = np.roll(kwargs['targets'], np.negative(delay))
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def __len__(self):
    return int(np.ceil((len(self.targets) - self.delay - self.length) / self.batch_size))
```

The delay parameter specifies how many steps are skipped.

```
a1=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]).reshape(-1,1)
a2=np.array([[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]]).reshape(-1,1)
b = np.concatenate((a1,a2), axis=1)
```

Using the standard TimeseriesGenerator on b would yield

```
[[1 2 3]] => [40]
[[2 3 4]] => [50]
[[3 4 5]] => [60]
[[4 5 6]] => [70]
[[5 6 7]] => [80]
[[6 7 8]] => [90]
```

Using the new class e.g., like this

```
ts_gen = TSGen(2, data=b[:,0],targets=b[:,1],length=3,batch_size=1,stride=1,sampling_rate=1)
```

would yield the following:

```
[[1 2 3]] => [60]
[[2 3 4]] => [70]
[[3 4 5]] => [80]
[[4 5 6]] => [90]
```